# iOS Application in Cydia and AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, cydia

I have an app in Cydia and I want to make the same application but LITE version and put it in AppStore. My question is will Apple reject my app if the check it some how. Actuality my app work with web services so I have real worked domain. And I want to use the same domain or to make another second lite-like domain of the original one...

Thank's in advance..

Comment: Hi I want to add our app in Cydia Store. How can i do this ?

Comment: Please tell me the process. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the yxflash team does a similar thing, they have a version of their application in Cydia (because, when they released it, the code was using private APIs), and they have another version (actually 3) in the AppStore called yxplayer. So from what I see there, you should be fine, apple doesn't seem to check those things.

Comment: Thank you... But should I change the domain and the web site or I can use the same?

Comment: @donjordano I wouldn't think that that would matter. As far as I know, apple does not check such things. To be safe, however you may wish to put your application on Cydia after it is released to the AppStore. And remember if this answer helped you, to vote up & accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an explicit violation of the iOS developer agreement; your presence in the App Store will depend on being obscure enough that Apple doesn't notice what you're doing and nobody tells them. That's not how I would want to do business, but to each their own?

> **7.3 No Other Distribution Authorized Under this Agreement**
>
> Except for the distribution of freely available Licensed Applications and the distribution of Applications for use on Registered Devices as set forth in Sections 7.1 and 7.2 above, no other distribution of programs or applications developed using the Apple Software is authorized or permitted hereunder. In the absence of a separate agreement with Apple, You agree not to distribute Your Application to third parties via other distribution methods or to enable or permit others to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Just submit the app, you will be fine.

Apple simply can't prove that YOU also submit the same app to Cydia.

That is, you can claim that your dog/cat/fish/wife/kid used the code to submit to Cydia during your sleep